# Twitter API - FINALIZE command failing after uploading chunked video

Tags: c#, twitter

I am uploading video to Twitter in chunks using Twitter Media API and then trying to call FINALIZE. 
Keep on getting:
"Large file can not be finalized synchronously."

```
result = new RequestBuilder(oauth, "POST", "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")
            .AddParameter("command", "FINALIZE")
            .AddParameter("media_id", media_id)
            .Execute().Result;

//code from Execute
            try
            {
                response = await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
 catch (WebException ex)
            {
                using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    ((IDisposable)response).Dispose();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I never received this exception. Have you tried using tweetinvi and see if it works for the same file?

Please note that Twitter only supports 15MB video.

Wiki for video upload : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Upload#upload-videos. The video are automatically chunked to satisfy Twitter requirements (5MB per chunk for video).

```
var video = File.ReadAllBytes("path");
var media = Upload.UploadVideo(video);
var tweet = Tweet.PublishTweet("hello", new PublishTweetOptionalParameters
{
    Medias = { media }
});
```

If you really want to do this manually you can still use the `ChunkUploader`:

https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Upload#chunked-uploads

Comment: yes I have tried your library. Not sure how to post full method here but using sample method from Tweetinvi I get object ref error in PublishTweet call. Can you please point me to uploading large video using this library?

    <code>var video = chunk.Complete(); 
            Tweet.PublishTweet("Tweet text:", new PublishTweetOptionalParameters()
            {
                Medias = new List<IMedia>() { video }
            });
        }
    </code>

Comment: when you say large, you mean a video lower than 15MB?

Comment: In this case, it was 23 MB.

Comment: Twitter only supports 15MB video.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter does support larger videos up to 512Mb, requirements can be found on this page: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/uploading-media/media-best-practices

In order to upload larger files you have to set the media_category parameter to "tweet_video" in the INIT call. The FINALIZE call will then give you processing_info that you need to follow up with the STATUS command call.

```js
.post("media/upload", {
      command: "INIT",
      total_bytes: mediaSize,
      media_type: mediaType,
      media_category: 'tweet_video'
  })
```